# Alarm bells, rings, or triggers?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, verbs, word-usage

Daily at 7 am, my alarm clock sounds "triiiinnngg'. Now, my concern is how do I describe alarm's action? I'm searching for a ***'verb'***.

> My alarm ***rings*** at 7 am.

Or

> My alarm ***bells*** at 7 am.

Or

> My alarm ***triggers*** at 7 am.

I heard somewhere that 'Alarm ***fires*** at 7 am'. Is 'fires' a correct word for an alarm in this context?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

> My alarm goes off.

Also, you might wanna take a look at [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10593/why-go-off-as-in-alarm-went-off) discussing the *why* of it.

If you worry that one might perceive a wrong image of "alarm", simply say

> My alarm clock went off this morning.

---

***Edit***: I find *going off* for an alarm clock the most viable and common choice. However, the OP seems to be seeking a feasible option among the three words they mention. So, among the three, the correct choice is...*drumrolls*...

> My alarm rings at 7 am.

Proof: I leave it for my first friend to prove it:

### [*My alarm rings at 7 am.*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22My+alarm+rings+at+7+am%22)

The sentence, excluding the adverbial phrase *at 7 a.m.*, returns 15500 results. With the adverbial phrase, it returns 208 results, including some from Google books, which means that the exact sentence is being used by others.

### [*My alarm triggers at 7 am.*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22My+alarm+triggers%22)

The sentence, excluding the adverbial phrase, returns 1920 results. With the phrase, only one result is found, and it's this very question. Here's why:

> trig·ger: *tr.v.*
>   1. To set off; initiate. [The free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trigger)

A lot of what you can make outta the verb *trigger* goes along the lines of *setting something off*, *activating it*. When you want to say a sentence with the context of an alarm waking you up in the morning, this sentence

> My alarm triggers at 7 am.

makes no sense. From the grammatical point of view, the sentence is lacking a direct object. "Your alarm triggered **what**, exactly?"

From the "meaning" view, *trigger* means *to activate*. It's not *you* who activates the alarm, because you're sleep. However, the meaning implies that this sentence is sensible:

> My mobile device has the functionality of triggering an alarm to wake me up every morning.

### [*My alarm bells at 7 am.*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFE_enIR614IR614&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22My+alarm+bells%22)

Excluding the adverbial phrase, there are some 26k results in Google. So, the phrase *my alarm bells* is very common. However, with the adverbial phrase, there are only 2 results of Google: One directing to this question and the other one to "ELL StackExchange - Newest questions". Here's why:

> *v.tr.*
>   1. To put a bell on.
>   2. To cause to flare like a bell.
>   *v.intr.*
>   To assume the form of a bell; flare. [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bell)

The verb form of *bell* is used for a very different purpose than what you had in mind. *Bells* (i.e. the noun form) are instruments that are (or rather were) used to *alarm* people. They look something like this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

<sub>This is a musical instrument.</sub>

Comment: I am asking about the most suitable word describing daily event of ringing alarm.  How can I describe it? it rings, bells, triggers, or fires?

Comment: @Ruchir Just as I said, it *goes off*. *Goes off* is a phrasal verb. So, it **is** a verb. But an alarm does *ring*, if it's really bothering you.

Comment: @Ruchir see edited answer. I hope it clears things up.

Comment: Yeah, *goes off* sounds like the best choice to me.

Comment: Goes off seems more to be the procedure and not the sound that I think op is concerned about

Comment: @Maulik the OP clearly states that they're looking for something that describes the alarm's action. Thus, *goes off* is the best choice.

Comment: @MaulikV I think it's [sense two in Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/go-off): "to start making a noise as a signal or warning".  They give the example "I was just lying in bed waiting for the alarm to go off."

Comment: @snailboat ah...that clarifies. Thanks... it's **utterly** new to me. I'll never forget this! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for ....

> The alarm *[rings](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/ring2_1)* at ...

Because `the alarm rang at 7 am` is quite a straight sentence with no ambiguity.

Precisely, you can say...

> The alarm *bell* rings at ...

If you have a digital alarm, you may say...

> The alarm *[beeps](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/beep_2)* at ...

Since you are concerned about the 'sound', I think 'ring' or 'beep' fits in!